Rotate map of Toronto in R
This is similar to How rotate map in R but the solution there doesn't work for me, probably because I'm a novice at mapping in R
I have a geojson file I downloaded from https://open.toronto.ca/dataset/neighbourhoods/
(They also provide .shp & other formats) I read it in and plot it:
library(geojsonio)
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
library(maptools)

tor_df <- geojson_read("Neighbourhoods140.geojson",  what="sp")

# Projection: WGS84

names(tor_df)

# [1] "X_id"                "AREA_ID"             "AREA_ATTR_ID"        "PARENT_AREA_ID"     
# [5] "AREA_SHORT_CODE"     "AREA_LONG_CODE"      "AREA_NAME"           "AREA_DESC"          
# [9] "CLASSIFICATION"      "CLASSIFICATION_CODE" "OBJECTID"    

head(tor_df$AREA_NAME)
# [1] "Brookhaven-Amesbury (30)" "Humewood-Cedarvale (106)" "Weston-Pelham Park (91)" 
# [4] "Hillcrest Village (48)"   "Agincourt North (129)"    "Yonge-St.Clair (97)" 

plot(tor_df, col = "pink")

And get:

From the answer mentioned above, I tried:
# This is technically an affine transformation: https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf3.html#affine-transformations-1
st_ellide_rotate = function(x, degrees, center_coords=NULL){
  if(degrees < -360 | degrees > 360) stop('Degrees must be in the range -360 to 360')
  x = sf::st_combine(x)
  if(is.null(center_coords)){
    center_coords = sf::st_centroid(x)
  }
  radians = degrees * pi/180
  transform_matrix = matrix(c(cos(radians), sin(radians), -sin(radians), cos(radians)), 2, 2)
  
  return((x-center_coords) * transform_matrix + center_coords)
}

tor_rotated <- tor_df %>%
  st_ellide_rotate(-20)
st_crs(tor_rotated) <- crs_save


But I get an error, and don't understand what to do to fix it,
  no applicable method for 'st_geometry' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialPolygonsNULL')"


You're importing your GeoJSON as a SpatialPolygonDataFrame from the sp package. You need to convert it to a simple features, aka sf object for the functions you are calling from the sf package (e.g., st_geometry) to work. Try amending your first line of code to tor_df <- geojsonio::geojson_sf("Neighbourhoods140.geojson").

Thanks for this. Perhaps there is a problem with this map or my code, but with the change to geojson_sf  I now get Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  :    Loop 50 edge 69 has duplicate near loop 124 edge 2

This error has to do with the sf package defaults. Try running sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE) at the top of your code. Also noticed the crs_save object is not defined anywhere (I assume it is earlier in your code if you're following the answer from the above linked SO thread?), but just in case, don't forget to set the CRS of your new tor_rotated object. Just checked the final results using ggplot() + geom_sf(data = tor_rotated) and it works.

sf::st_read() and geojsonsf::geojson_sf() are both generally quicker than geojsonio
